# Validation (@Size or @NotEmpty) is not working for Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I created a cimple program, and I want to add validation for my field (`firstName` and `secondName`).I use annotations `@Size` and `@NotEmpty`, but all my app works except validation.

```
/**
* model
*/
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class User {
    @Size(min = 2, message = "Field must be min 2 symbols!")
    private String firstName;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Field is required")
    private String secondName;
    private String department;
    private Map<String, String> departments;

    public User() {
        departments = new HashMap<>();
        departments.put("IT", "Information Technology");
        departments.put("HR", "Human Resources");
        departments.put("Sales", "Sales");
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getDepartments() {
        return departments;
    }

    public void setDepartments(Map<String, String> departments) {
        this.departments = departments;
    }
}
```

```
/**
* Controller
*/
import com.zherikhov.models.User;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String showFirstView() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/authorization")
    public String showAuthorization(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "authorization";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String showDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "authorization";
        } else {
            return "welcome";
        }
    }
}
```

```
/**
* authorization.jsp
*/
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <p>Authorization</p>
        <form:form action="welcome" modelAttribute="user">
            <div>
                <label>Please enter your First name</label>
                <form:input path="firstName"/>
                <form:errors path="firstName"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Please enter your Second name</label>
                <form:input path="secondName"/>
                <form:errors path="secondName"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Please choose your department</label>
                <form:select path="department">
                    <form:options items="${user.departments}"/>
                </form:select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
            </div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

```
/**
* welcome.jsp
*/
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<h2>Authorization was successful!</h2>
First name - ${user.firstName}
<br>
Second name - ${user.secondName}
<br>
Department -  ${user.department}
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.zherikhov</groupId>
  <artifactId>myAccounting</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>myAccounting Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.myAccounting.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.27</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>myAccounting</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

I added annotations `@Size` and `@NotEmpty` for my fields, and when I will be to press button send, I have to see error, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Please add pom/gradle file to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation `jakarta.validation.Valid` will not fire in Spring5/Java11 - it's for Spring6/Java17.

Change

```
public String showDetails(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

to

```
public String showDetails(@Validated @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult)
```

where `@Validated` is `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated`